# call a method on a controller from another controller in mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, castle-windsor

I want to call a method on another controller. The problem is that in my project, all controllers are created using Windsor castle and Windsor castle resolve the dependencies. This means that I cannot instantiate a controller by using new as then it needs its dependents. How can ask MVC to instantiate a controller and then call a method on it (which returns an object)?

Comment: do you have some code you can post so we can better understand your approach?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to tell you two things: 1) First, I'll show you how you'll most likely be able to accomplish what you want, and 2) Then I'll recomment you achieve your goal in another way :)

1: When using auto-wiring, the way to get stuff from the container is to declare the dependency by adding it as a constructor argument - e.g. (assuming the container knows how to resolve controllers by their concrete types):

```
public class HomeController
{
    readonly AccountController accountController;

    public HomeController(AccountController accountController)
    {
        this.accountController = accountController;
    }
}
```

This will most likely allow you to do what you want with `AccountController` from withing `HomeController`. However, this is not very pretty.

2: Injecting one controller into another is probably not what you (really) want. I'm guessing that you really want to move whatever logic you have in your controller's action method into a dedicated service, e.g. `DoSomethingInteresting` which happens to implement `IDoStuff`, and then let both of your controllers depend on `IDoStuff`. Does this make sense to you?